# Macro to export XLSM file to PDF without cutting off

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to export my XLSM file to PDF, but when I run the code, you can barely see anything due to cut off in the PDF version.

this is my code:

```
Sub ExporterPDF():

Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strDate As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant

 
On Error GoTo Erreur


Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet


'Récupérer le chemin d'accès du fichier
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

 
'Créer nom du fichier pour la sauvegarde
strDate = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")
strName = "TableauBord"
strFile = strDate & "_" & strName & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

 

'Sélectionner répertoire pour sauvegarde
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Enregistrez sous...")

 

'Enregistrer le PDF si un répertoire a été sélectionné
If myFile <> False Then
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'Message de confirmation
    MsgBox "Le fichier PDF a bien été enregistré : "
End If


Done:
    Exit Sub
Erreur:
    MsgBox "Le fichier PDF n'a pu être créé."
    Resume Done
    
End Sub
```

How to fit everything in the PDF file?! Any help is greatly appreciated. thank you so much all for reading!

Comment: Did you try to set the `Margins` to `Narrow` from the `Page Layout` tab?

Comment: I tried that, but nothing. Same result...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'Enregistrer le PDF si un répertoire a été sélectionné
If myFile <> False Then
    wsA.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = wsa.Range("A1:E10")
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.4)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    End With
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'Message de confirmation
    MsgBox "Le fichier PDF a bien été enregistré : "
End If
```